# Calling javascript from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't even know what to call this, i'm very very new with javascript so i'm sure the answer is simple. The situation is this: A javascript script is building a search pane in html using another sites API. The amount of items in the list are undetermined, hence why it's grabbing them with javascript. I'm using [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) on one of the option lists that is generated from the API. I've got javascript generating the HTML correctly (option tags nested in a select tag, with a div wrapper around them) But now I need to put in the call script. in html this is done with:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').multiselect();
});
</script>`
```

but since i'm building the elements with javascript, how do i do this? is it easier? more complicated. Like I said i'm a newbie at this so i'm at a complete loss.

Here's the chunk of code that generates the multiselect list. I don't fully understand the whole script that pulls the API data, but I rewrote this chunk and it seems to work.

```
 function renderCheck (options, attr) {
 var $wrapper = $('<select>').attr({id: attr.id, name: attr.id, style: 'display: block;', class: 'field col-12 mb1', multiple: 'multiple'})
var idKey = attr.primaryKey ? attr.primaryKey : 'Id'

$.each(options, function(i, item) {
  var $itemWrapper = $('<option>').attr({class: 'filter-item', value:item[idKey]}).text(item.Name)

  $wrapper.append($itemWrapper);
})
return $wrapper
}
```

Comment: So after you append the element to the page, than do `$wrapper.multiselect();`

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: You have to call the mutiselect code after you append it to the document. You do not show how you add it to the page so I can not help.

Comment: What @epascarello is saying I understand is to call the `$wrapper.multiselect()` at some point later than the function that calls `renderCheck`. That is after you append the check and other items to the DOM.

Comment: `check: function (endpoint, attr) {`

           `var d = $.Deferred()`

           `api[endpoint]().then(function (options) {`

            `d.resolve(renderCheck(options, attr))`

          `})`

          `return d.promise()`

         `$wrapper.multiselect()`

        `},`

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

Never could figure out the answer, possibly due to my own incompetence with javascript (pretty sure i couldn't write a hello world script in javascript if i had a gun to my head). Have decided to go another way that won't require me rewriting that section of code.